# When to use "and" while reading prices?

Tags: pronunciation

I've watched many videos with different accents about how to read prices but I got confused about the usage of the word "and".

When is it a must? When is it optional? When is it omitted? I would like the answer to be according to the American accent.

Here are some numbers that I would like to read:

$4.85 
Is it four dollars AND eighty five cents?

$67.98 
Is it sixty seven dollars AND ninety eight cents?

Here's another type of "and":

$123.50
 is it one hundred AND twenty three dollars AND fifty cents?

$1123.50 Is this one thousand one hundred AND twenty three dollars AND fifty cents?

Now, how do you pronounce this?
$345,489.12

**Edit: **

According to comments, I'd like to add the situation. Soon, I'll be a customer service representative (Through phone) for a well-known fast food company. When people ask me about the price, I'll try to say the short version but I know that short versions may lead to confusion (e.g. the funny story in the comments). I would like to learn the full version (especially the word "and") to be able to handle customers that get confused.

Thank you so much,

Comment: For clarity you can use the full version, but if it is clear that you are talking about money (say at the store checkout), you don't need to say *dollars/cents* or *and*. For example, $4.85 would be "four eighty five". The full version would be best for very large numbers, as some error would be rather troublesome. In your question, you should add the situation where these phrases would be used, but in the final analysis it is likely personal preference rather than a rule.

Comment: @user3169 - Your comment is spot on and it reminds me of a funny story. I wanted to show my children how pricey a jewelry store can be, so we walked into one at the mall one day. I pointed to a somewhat modest ring under the glass and asked, "How much for that one?" The woman replied, "Fourteen ninety-five." We walked out, and my youngest daughter said, "That's not so bad." (She assumed it was a $15 dollar ring.) When I explained what "fourteen ninety-five" meant in a jewelry store, her chin almost hit the floor.

Comment: For the longer numbers, this is one of those situations that differs between British and American English. The number 1,234 is "one thousand, two hundred thirty-four" in strictly-correct American English, but it is "one thousand, two hundred **and** thirty-four" in strictly-correct British English.  That said, you'll find that many AmE speakers will still use the **and**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you pronounce this? $345,489.12

I would say it like this:

> Three hundred eighty-five thousand [*short pause*] four hundred eighty-nine dollars [*short pause*] and twelve cents.

The only place I would put an "and" is after the word *dollars*.

As an extra note, it would not be "wrong" put an "and" in the middle of one of the numbers (for example, "Three hundred **and** eighty-five thousand..."). However, it is not needed, and I'd be inclined to omit it, particularly if you are going to spend a good portion of your day reading large numbers over the phone.